# using partition returns unexpected result

Tags: elasticsearch

Query does not gives result as expected:

when query without using partition the query will return correct result: it will return the max view of all products.

But when partition is used, it won't return the max total view.

```
get product/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cars": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type.keyword",
        "include": {
          "partition": 0,
          "num_partitions": 5
        },
        "order": {
          "productHits": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "productHits": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "hits"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

expected:

```
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "a car",
          "doc_count" : 383,
          "productHits" : {
            "value" : 209.0
          }]
```

actual:

```
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "another car",
          "doc_count" : 383,
          "productHits" : {
            "value" : 9.0
          }]
```

a car has the highest hits of all.

Comment: May I ask you what does ES return if you query for other partitions: 1, 2 3, 4?

Comment: May you please provide a couple of example documents and the mapping you are using?